# How to add name attribute for input tag based on name of link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using bootstrap-editable of bootstrap3 library. I want to set attribute 'name' of link tag for input tag. Ex: My link tag name is 'username' now I want when I click on it then display text input tag have attribute name="username". How can I do that?

```
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username" name="username">superuser</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
        //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

        //make companyname editable
        $('#username').editable();

        //make status editable
        $('#username').editable({
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            url: '/post',
            title: 'Enter user name',
        });
    });
```

Comment: you want to add a new input tag?

Comment: display text input tag have attribute name="username" 
Do you mean input tag will show this as value or input tag will have this as name attribute?

Comment: you can try `$("input").tagsinput('items')`

Comment: because this is a library of bootstrap so how can I chang in file js?